# Concoct the series $\sum a_n$ such that $(-1)^na_n>0, a_n \rightarrow 0$ , but the series diverges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I came across the following in Chapman pugh's analysis:

> Concoct the series $\sum a_n$ such that $(-1)^na_n>0, a_n \rightarrow 0$ , but the series diverges.

I found one example: take $$a_n=\frac{1+2(-1)^n}{2n}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}+(-1)^n}{n}$$
Then $a_n \rightarrow 0$ and $(\forall n \in \Bbb{N}):(-1)^na_n>0$. Also $\sum a_n$ diverges.

---

My questions are

- Is this example correct ? or any other easy example?
- What is the importance of this problem ? Is this just a warm up exercise in that book ?  Is there any other information about this problem?

Any help must be appreciated and thanks in advance!

Comment: Your example is fine, just like $$a_n=\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}\frac{1}{n+1}&\text{if}&n\text{ is even}\\-\frac{1}{n^2}&\text{if}&n\text{ is odd}\end{array}\right.$$ I believe that the main point of the exercise is to make you realize that $|a_n|$ cannot be *decreasing* to zero, otherwise $\sum a_n$ would be convergent by Leibniz test.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: What's wrong in my example? can you explain it a bit more please?

Comment: My bad, I misread your definition. I edited my previous comment.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: Ok